# Arrays and jQuery / PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$images = array();
  foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    $images['src'] = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
    $images['user'] = $data->user->username;
    $images['time'] = $data->created_time;
  }

  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $pagination->next_page,
    'images'  => array('src' => $images['src'], 'user' => $images['user'], 'time' => $images['time'])

  ));
```

I want it to display all the fields but it only outputs one. How Ccn I make it display all the fields on json output?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean use all the images in `$media->data`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need array of images, not single image:

```
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    $image=array();
    $image['src'] = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
    $image['user'] = $data->user->username;
    $image['time'] = $data->created_time;
    $images[]=$image;
  }
```

other possible syntax is:

```
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    $images[]=array(
    'src'  => $data->images->thumbnail->url,
    'user' => $data->user->username,
    'time' => $data->created_time
   );
  }
```

json encode part also should be changed:

```
 echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $pagination->next_page,
    'images'  => $images)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = array();
foreach ($media->data as $data) {
  $images[]=array(
    'src'  => $data->images->thumbnail->url,
    'user' => $data->user->username,
    'time' => $data->created_time
  );
}

echo json_encode(array(
  'next_id' => $pagination->next_page,
  'images'  => $images
));
```

Comment: Do add some explanation on why this approach is better, though for you, the problem (or solution) might be readable in the code, the real answer is in explaining why this is an improvement. If textually improved, I'll +1 it :)

Comment: I'm not good know English for write explanation. Sorry. I'm just give solution. (and @eicto copyed it)